# How to make list view items clickable? Android SQL Lite DB

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, clickable

i will attempt to keep this short and concise. I am currently developing an android application, and am stuck on a particular element.

The below is an example code i have been reading through, from my understanding it is taking a list of values inserting them in to the db / table, then cycling through them with the cursor and displaying with the list view. 
On running the application all items are displayed in a list as expected.

I would like it so that when an item in the list is clicked a new page is opened via intent, or a different set of database values is displayed on the current page.

How could this be achieved

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement this method

> ```
> protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
> ```
>
> This method will be called when an item in the list is selected. Subclasses should override. Subclasses can call `getListView().getItemAtPosition(position)` if they need to access the data associated with the selected item.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - `l`    `ListView`: The ListView where the click happened
> - `v`    `View`: The view that was clicked within the ListView
> - `position` `int`: The position of the view in the list
> - `id` `long`: The row id of the item that was clicked

[ListActivity - Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html)

Comment: Thank you this has been implemented, and am using it via intent to open a page, now i just need to look at how a certain set of data could be displayed on the button click. Thanks

Comment: If this answers your question, then you may use the checkmark next to the answer to let others on the site know that.